# An operator with infinite deficiency index

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm looking for a simple example of an operator with infinite [deficiency index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator)  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ be two infinite disjoint sets of the same cardinality. Let $i:\Gamma_1\to \Gamma_2$ be a bijection, then define $\Gamma=\Gamma_1\bigcup \Gamma_2$. One can easily show that
$$
V:\ell_2(\Gamma)\to \ell_2(\Gamma):x\mapsto\left(\gamma\mapsto\begin{cases} x_{i(\gamma)}&\quad\text{ if }\quad \gamma\in\Gamma_1\\0&\quad\text{ if }\quad \gamma\in\Gamma_2\end{cases}\right)
$$ 
is a partial isometry. Moreover
$$
n_{+}(V)
=\dim(\operatorname{dom}(V)^{\perp})
=\dim(\ell_2(\Gamma_1)^\perp)
=\dim(\ell_2(\Gamma_2))
=|\Gamma_2|\geq\aleph_0\\
n_{-}(V)
=\dim(\operatorname{ran}(V)^{\perp})
=\dim(\ell_2(\Gamma_2)^\perp)
=\dim(\ell_2(\Gamma_1))
=|\Gamma_1|\geq\aleph_0\\
$$